# Why do I get the error "Floating point exception"?

Tags: c++, perfect-numbers

I am trying to write a code that finds perfect numbers lower than the user's input.
Sample of correct output:

> Enter a positive integer: 100
>   6 is a perfect number
>   28 is a perfect number
>   There are no more perfect numbers less than or equal to 100

But when I run my code, I get the error `Floating point exception`

and can not figure out why. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isAFactor(int, int);

int main(){
    int x, y;
    int countOut, countIn;
    int userIn;
    int perfect = 0;

    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> userIn;

    for(countOut = 0; countOut < userIn; countOut++){
        for(countIn = 1; countIn <= countOut; countIn++){
            if(isAFactor(countOut, countIn) == true){
                countOut = countOut + perfect;
            }
        }

        if(perfect == countOut){
            cout << perfect << " is a perfect number" << endl;
        }

        perfect++;
    }

    cout << "There are no more perfect numbers less than or equal to " << userIn << endl;

    return 0;
}


bool isAFactor(int inner, int outer){
    if(outer % inner == 0){
        return true;
    }

    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calculating x % 0.

Comment: It would help if you posted the real error message. I'm quite sure no compiler ever says "acception". It's also a little odd that you have floating point errors in code that is integer only.

Comment: "Floating point EXception"

The calculation goes x % 1. Doesn't it?

It is weird that I get that error message with only int and bool values. That is why I am asking the question :P

Comment: 1) Yes, it does. Check your `isAFactor` function. 2) Doesn't matter. "_The SIGFPE signal is sent to a process when it executes an erroneous arithmetic operation, such as division by zero._"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify @Aki Suihkonen's comment, when performing:
  `outer % inner`
If `inner` is zero, you will get a *divide by zero* error.

This can be traced backward by calling `isAFactor(0, 1)`.
It is in your `for` loop in `main`.

The first parameter to `isAFactor(countOut, countIn)` is assigned in the outermost `for` loop:
`for (countOut = 0; ...`

Notice the value you are initializing `countOut` with.

**Edit 1:**

```
Change your `isAFactor` function to:  

    if (inner == 0)
    {
       cerr << "Divide by zero.\n";
       cerr.flush();
       return 0;
    }
    if (outer % inner ...
```

Place a breakpoint at either `cerr` line above.
When the execution stops there, look at the *Stack Trace*.  A good debugger will also allow you to examine the parameter / values at each point in the trace.

Comment: I have changed 'bool isAFactor(int inner, int outer)' to 'isAFactor(int outer, int inner)' so it does not devide by zero anymore. But the same error message is displayed.

Comment: See my **Edit 1:**.  Use a debugger.

Comment: Thank you, I can see now where the problem lies. but I still don't understand why it is dividing by zero. I even tried 'if(inner == 0){ inner++;}'

Answer (score 1):

The arguments are just swapped. You are calling the function as `isAFactor(countOut, countIn)` when you should be calling with `isAFactor(countIn, countOut)`

Comment: I tried that, still gives the same error...thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: I changed my isAFactor to isAFactor(int outer, int inner) but it still doesn't work....still the same error